# Regex excluding specific characters

Tags: regex

In [this lesson](http://regexone.com/lesson/4?) I don't understand why `[^b]` is not correct? I understand that `[^bog]` is correct.

`[^b]` should match any string that has no `b` character and don't match any string containing any `b` character.

Is there anything wrong in my understanding?

Comment: `[^b]` matches a character that is not a `b`. So in your `hog / bog / dog` example, it matches all of them since all words have a letter in them that is not a `b`. `[^bog]` actually matches any character that is neither a `b`, nor `o`, nor `g`, that's why it does not match any letter of `bog`. Neither would it match `gob` or `ogb` etc. The answer to that question, by the way, could just be `[dh]og` to match `dog`, `hog`, but not `bog`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

For that specific [lesson](http://regexone.com/lesson/4?), the correct `regex` is:

```
[^b]og
```

***EXPLANATION:***

```
/[^b]og/

[^b] match a single character not present in the list below
b the literal character b (case sensitive)
og matches the characters og literally (case sensitive)
```

***NOTES:***

> ***[Negated Character Classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)***
>
> Typing a **caret** after the **opening square bracket negates the character
>   class**. The result is that the character class matches any character
>   that is not in the character class. Unlike the dot, negated character
>   classes also match (invisible) line break characters. If you don't
>   want a negated character class to match line breaks, you need to
>   include the line break characters in the class. **[^0-9\r\n]** matches any
>   character that is not a digit or a line break.
>
> It is important to remember that a **negated character class** still must
>   match a character. **q[^u]** does not mean: "**a q not followed by a u**". It
>   means: "**a q followed by a character that is not a u**". It does not
>   match the **q** in the string **Iraq**. It does match the **q** and the **space**
>   after the **q** in ***Iraq is a country***. Indeed: the space becomes part of
>   the overall match, because it is the "**character that is not a u**" that
>   is matched by the **negated character class** in the above regexp. If you
>   want the regex to match the **q**, and only the **q**, in both strings, you
>   need to use `negative lookahead`.

Comment: I +1'ed yours because some reason I didn't think of the expression they were actually looking for.  However, I think you could answer OP's direct question better.

Comment: @sam I think the ***`explanation`*** is self explanatory.

Comment: I think the explanation section is good, but OP's question is why doesn't `[^b]` work.  That isn't addressed in the explanation.

Answer (score 11):

`^[^b]` works.

The `^` OUTSIDE the `[]`s indicates "the beginning of the string"

Answer (score 11):

`[^b]` will only match one character that is not 'b'.
`[^b]+` will specify that RegEx group to match one or more characters that are not 'b'.
`[^b]*` will specify that RegEx group to match zero or more characters that are not 'b'.

Answer (score 5):

You are fundamentally correct, but `[^b]` will still match `o` and `g` in `bog` -- meaning it is a successful match, even though it didn't match the whole string.  `[^bog]` will only match `h` in `hog`, `d` in `dog`, and nothing in `bog` -- meaning it doesn't match `bog`.

I think this will make more sense if you look at [`^[^b]+$`](http://regex101.com/r/jC2vQ6).  This will match `1+` non-`b` characters, anchored at the beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of the string.  Comparing that to your initial expression of [`[^b]`](http://regex101.com/r/sN5oF7) or [`[^bog]`](http://regex101.com/r/nG5iR1), you can see the difference.  I suggest using a GUI RegEx tester (the previously linked one is my favorite), which will really help illustrate the logic.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this with inputFormatter in flutter language

This will exclude emoji and this special character.
If you want to add number also you can put into this.

```
 inputFormatter: <TextInputFormatter>[
          FilteringTextInputFormatter.deny(r'[¬¦्«»ΩΠμ§¡¿±·£%,!#$%&*+";:/=?^`{|}~₹)(•√π÷×¶∆€¥¢°©®™✓><\[\]\\’|‘|”|“|]\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff]')
]
```