# Match lines that do not contain certain character

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I need to match lines that do not contain the capital letter 'K'.  The character 'K' could start the line, could be in the middle, or could be the next to last character.  I have tried both negative look-ahead, but that seems to fail when 'K' starts the line.

I want to keep these lines:

> Coronograph H-band  / Y Direct / Non-Redundant J

But I want to exclude these lines:

> 'Coronograph K1-band / K2 Direct / Non-Redundant K2'

I need it to work in both python regex engine, and JavaScript regex engine, so I can't use look-behind expressions.

When I try things like `.*[^K]+`, or `.*[^K].*`, it still matches the lines with 'K' in them.

I get from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23352038/regex-excluding-specific-characters) why I can't just say `[^K]` and be done with it.  But since my 'K' may or may not have a character to start, I'm confused on how to proceed.  If I say `.[^K]`, or `.*[^K]`, it will still match 'K2 Direct'.  If I say `[^K].` or `[^K].*`, it will match the lines where 'K' does not start the line.

Maybe I'm grasping at straws here, but in my list, the 'K' will either be followed by a '1' or a '2'.  Could I do something like `[^K][^12]`?  But again, I'm still stumped on what kind of prefix/suffix to put to match it's variable position in the line.

Comment: `/(?!K)/` is the solution you are looking for. A lot less flexible would be `/^[^k]+$/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex: `^[^K]*$` for python and javascript.

This regex resembles a line starting (`^`) and containing only non capital letters `K` until the end of the line `$`.

Comment: Which definition of regex are you going for? What operators are allowed? There are many kinds of regular expression basis.

Comment: I say in the question, JavaScript and python.  I can have two different syntaxes.  My python code takes the JavaScript regex expression and changes it for the python regex matching.  But I'd like to keep them similar, without getting crazy switching between the two.

Comment: I just tried `[^K]*`, but it still matched the line 'K1 Direct' (using the python regex) and it matched 'Coronograph K2'.

Comment: Wow!  That worked (in both python and JavaScript) and was stupid simple.  I wasted a day and a half to this.  Thanks!