# Exclude arrow symbol in regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have this regex:

```
r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*(?!\d+\s+)\S+(?:\s+(?!\d+\b)\S+)*\s*2\s+(?!\d+\b)\S+(?:\s+(?!\d+\b)\S+)*\s*$"
```

That matches

```
] prima 1 words 2 words
```

And excludes 3

However, this also matches:

```
] prima 1 words → 2 words
```

How to exclude → ?

Comment: [No matches](https://regex101.com/r/vGwVqt/1).

Comment: the asterisk was to make understand "one or more words". Edited the question

Comment: And excluding means it excludes the 3.

Comment: [Still no matches](https://regex101.com/r/vGwVqt/2).

Comment: You have to delete the 3, it excludes the 3!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex excluding specific characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23352038/regex-excluding-specific-characters)

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work...

Comment: Works for me [like this](https://regex101.com/r/vGwVqt/1)

Comment: It matches this, though: https://regex101.com/r/vGwVqt/3

Comment: You can exclude it using `[^\s→]+` instead of `\S+` https://regex101.com/r/eqGzDI/1

Comment: perfect, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try `r"\]\s*prima\s*1\s*(?![\d]+\s+)([^\s→]+(?:\s+(?![\d]+\b)[^\s→]+)*)\s*2\s+(?![\d]+\b)([^\s→]+(?:\s+(?![\d]+\b)[^\s→]+)*)\s*$"`

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/NLCFdp/1)